# iOS5 Swipe Gesture to switch images - help requested

Tags: xcode, uiview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a number of images that I'd like to push using gestures (back and forth). I know that the PageViewController is perfect for this, but I cannot figure out how to use this in an existing project that uses NIBs.

So. I'm trying to build a UIView Animation. I can see the first image, but the gestures are not working..

I would appreciate any help..

Here is the code for one of the two routines, plus the gesture init:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    return YES;
}


- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

     NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
     switch (recognizer.direction)
     {
          case (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight):
               [self performSelector:@selector(previousPage:)];
               //[self previousPage];
               break;               

          case (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft): 
               [self performSelector:@selector(nextPage:)];
               //[self nextPage];
               break;

          default:
               break;
     }     
}     



- (void)nextPage {
     [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeOut" context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0f];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
     [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
     pageNumber ++;
     if(pageNumber > maxInfoPages)
     {
          pageNumber = 1;
     }
     NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"infoPage%i.png", pageNumber];
     imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];     
     NSLog(@"imageName is: %@", imageName);                                    
     NSLog(@"imageView is: %@", imageView);
     imageView.clipsToBounds=YES;     
     self.view = imageView;
     [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Did you attach the gesture recognizer to the view in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up switching out my original code for PageViewController code. The samples from that are from Erica Sadun's new book: "iOS5 Developer's Cookbook" .. The book will be [published](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0132930811) on Nov. 14 but the [code samples](https://github.com/erica/iOS-5-Cookbook) are available to pre-purchasers..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually set up the UIGestureRecognizers and add them to your view, you will not get any events sent to your viewController.  So you need to attach the UIGestureRecognizers to the view that will intercept the swipes.  For example in your viewDidLoad method you would do something along the lines of:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipe=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
rightSwipe.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
leftSwipe.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipe];

// leave out the following if using ARC
[leftSwipe release];
[rightSwipe release];
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Tim, thanks, but he gestures are there. In fact I had the gestures working, but the pages were blank. I've gotten the pages to show image. (at least in the log files) , but now the gestures ave stopped.. I will check to see that the gestures are linked to this view. They may be in the app delegate...